# Connecting to a Progress 8.3d Database

Tags: c#, openedge, erp, progress-db

One of my company's clients has requested a program that will access their ERP's Database and manipulate some of the data that their ERP package does not have.

However, their systems are pretty old and they haven't upgraded in over a decade.  The database that handles their ERP package is a Progress 8.3d database that was released in 2001.

I have tried looking into ways of connecting to this but I really have no clue, The application that we will be writing will most probably be C# on the .NET framework of at least 3.5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really an answer, and I don't know 'Progress' Databases. But are there ODBC Drivers available for that DB system? If so, you could use those.

Comment: Right as you answered I finally found it haha. [They do provide an ODBC driver packaged with the database](http://www.datadirect.com/products/odbc/progress_database_odbc_driver_faqs.html) I will have to contact them about this.